# NHibernate HQL batch update fails with "specified method not supported" exception

Tags: nhibernate, hql

When trying to do an HQL batch update for Order entity, I'm getting the following exception:

```
   Specified method is not supported.
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.PolymorphicQuerySourceDetector.GetClassName(IASTNode querySource)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.PolymorphicQuerySourceDetector.Process(IASTNode tree)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.AstPolymorphicProcessor.Process()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.AstPolymorphicProcessor.Process(IASTNode ast, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryString, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String hql, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan..ctor(String hql, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan..ctor(String hql, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(String queryString, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(String query, Boolean shallow)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(String queryString)
   at ...Repositories.OrderRepository.MarkAsConfirmed(IEnumerable`1 orderIds) in C:\Users\Miroslav\Documents\Projects\...\OrderRepository.cs:line 40
   at ConfirmationUploadTask.Execute()
```

Note that the **Order** entity is mapped to **Orders** table, so there *shouldn't* be any reserved-keyword related issues. Other LINQ 2 NHibernate based queries are working properly. When using some other mapped entity instead of Order, the query works.

I've also tried with `hbm2ddl.keywords=auto-quote` [as mentioned by Fabio](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/06/auto-quote-tablecolumn-names.html), but with no luck.

For reference, this is what the query looks like:

```
var query = GetSession().CreateQuery(
    "update Order set IsConfirmed = :isConfirmed where id in (:ids)");
```

When using CreateSQLQuery instead, it works without errors:

```
var query = GetSession().CreateSQLQuery(
    "UPDATE Orders SET IsConfirmed = :isConfirmed WHERE OrderId in (:ids)");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's a bug; please open a ticket at http://jira.nhforge.org

As a workaround, qualify the name of the Order entity. Example:

```
update MyProj.Domain.Order set IsConfirmed = :isConfirmed where id in (:ids)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your workaround worked as expected. I've submitted a bug to JIRA: http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-2562